# Ionic 4 ion-select-option value change

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on a migration from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4. I have something like this in my ionic 3 page:

```
    <ion-select ...>
        <ion-select-option (ionSelect)="myFucntion()" otherstuff...>Value</ion-select-option>
        ...other selection options
    </ion-select>
```

So basically, every time user selects this specific select, it's run a myFunction(). How can I do the same in Ionic 4? There is no (ionSelect) event. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @alex87 The only solution for me was to create custom control using the Ionic AlertController. If you still interested I can add the solution later.

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace (ionSelect) with (ionChange)

Comment: `(ionSelect)` is not part of ionic 4's `<ion-select-option>`